# Role Based Access Control with permission constraints through certain attributes

Tags: permissions, authorization, rbac, xacml, abac

Every user has one or more roles, every role has one or more permissions. So far I can gather all permissions that are associated to a user via the roles.

### The Problem

Some permissions have some constraints. For example:

> A user can edit all posts that belong to his site, but no other posts.

Therefore the permission "edit post" should have this constraint.

Regarding the model: If the Constraints are related to the permission, I can't resolve which constraints are active for the particular user.

The user model can have an attribute like "site", but not all users, that belong to one site should have the constraint mentioned above. Some of them should be able to edit all posts.

### Question

What is the best way to determine which constraint is active for a particular user. Do I have to split this into seperate permissions and integrate the constraints into the permission model or is there a better solution? I stumbled upon attribute based access control but I am not sure if I should switch to a completely different appoach

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I replied the following to a previous similar question

You want to use a solution that is *agnostic* of the type of application it protects. That's the goal of XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language.

XACML provides attribute-based, policy-based access control (ABAC and PBAC). This gives you the ability to write extremely expressive authorization policies and managed them centrally in a single repository. A central authorization engine (called Policy Decision Point or PDP) will then serve decisions to your different applications.

The minimum set of attributes you will need is typically attributes about the user (Subject), the resource, and the action. XACML also lets you add environment attributes. This means you can write the following type of policy:

> Doctors can view the medical records of patients they are assigned to.

- *Doctors* describes the user / subject
- *view* describes the action
- *medical records* describes the targeted resource
- *of patients* describes the targeted resource too. It's metadata about the resource
- *they are assigned to* is an interesting case. It's an attribute that defines the relationship between the doctor and the patient. In ABAC, this gets implemented as doctor.id==patient.assignedDoctorId. This is one of the key benefits of using XACML.

Benefits of XACML include:
 - the ability to externalize the authorization logic as mentioned by Bell
 - the ability to update authorization logic without going through a development/deployment lifecycle
 - the ability to have fine-grained authorization implemented the same way for many different applications
 - the ability to have visibility and audits on the authorization logic

HTH

Comment: Thx for the quick response. I will look into it. The framework for the implementation will be laravel which might fit quite well regarding the policies that can be used. Even though I will need some time to get a deeper understanding of ABAC. Apart from that, I will have a look at XACML which might be a good start to build that understanding :)

Comment: I think laravel has all you need. It doesn't use XACML but it has similar capabilities